# I import JUnit to Eclipse and still does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am new to Java and our teacher told us to import the JUnit libraries to our proyect to learn how to use it. I have tried importing the JUnit 5 library to the buildpath and it does not work, and also tried with the version the teacher told us to import and still not working.
[Here is the path with the version the teacher told us to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwKJe.png)
[I am getting the "is not accesible" error as if junit was not in the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAZ96.png)

Again I tried also adding the JUnit5 library to the path but it still does not work for me.

Comment: Java 22 which has been released two days ago and which has no long term support would require Eclipse 2024-03 with the [Java 22 Support for Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-22-support-eclipse-2024-03-431). But better use the current Eclipse with included Java 17. All you have to do is _File > New > JUnit Test Case_, choosing _New JUnit Jupiter test_ (JUnit 5) and confirm adding the required libraries to the Java Build Path. As beginner, better make sure not to have a `module-info.java` file.